# Using Qt Creator with Allegro

Tags: c++, windows, qt-creator, allegro

I want to get Allegro 4 (MSCV 9) to work with Qt Creator. I am using Windows XP.
I have added these lines to my .pro:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/Allegro/include \
LIBS += C:/Allegro/lib/allegro-4.4.2-md.lib \
        C:/Allegro/lib/allegro-4.4.2-monolith-md.lib \
        C:/Allegro/lib/allegrogl-0.4.4-md.lib \
        C:/Allegro/lib/loadpng-1.5-md.lib \
```

My code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <allegro.h>

volatile int closedWindow = false;

void CloseButtonCallback() {closedWindow = true;}
END_OF_FUNCTION(CloseButtonCallback())

int main()
{
    allegro_init();
    set_color_depth(32);
    set_gfx_mode(GFX_AUTODETECT_WINDOWED, 400, 300, 0, 0);
    set_window_title("Testing");

    LOCK_FUNCTION(closeButtonCallback)
    set_close_button_callback(CloseButtonCallback);
    while(!closedWindow){}
    allegro_exit();
    return 0;
}
END_OF_MAIN()
```

And I keep getting errors like these, when I try to compile:

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol **imp__allegro_exit referenced in function "int __cdecl _mangled_main(void)" (?_mangled_main@@YAHXZ)
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_set_close_button_callback referenced in function "int __cdecl _mangled_main(void)" (?_mangled_main@@YAHXZ)
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_set_window_title referenced in function "int __cdecl _mangled_main(void)" (?_mangled_main@@YAHXZ)
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_set_gfx_mode referenced in function "int __cdecl _mangled_main(void)" (?_mangled_main@@YAHXZ)
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_set_color_depth referenced in function "int __cdecl _mangled_main(void)" (?_mangled_main@@YAHXZ)
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp**_install_allegro_version_check referenced in function "int __cdecl _mangled_main(void)" (?_mangled_main@@YAHXZ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using precompiled Allegro 4.4 for MinGW from http://www.allegro.cc/files/. I merged those three folders (bin, include, lib) inside the archive to MinGW folder which has same folders as well. Then added `LIBS += liballegro-4.4.2-mt` to .pro file and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to use the GCC-compiled version of Allegro for Qt.

Something like

```
LIBS +="path_to_allegro_for_mingw/lib/liballegro-4.4.2-md.a"
```

GCC uses different name mangling and different export libraries, so even while you're using the Allegro dlls, MSVC-compiled .lib wouldn't work.